# $f(x) \to 0$ faster than $x \to \infty \implies f'(x) \to 0$ faster than $x \to \infty$ too?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Say you have $f(x)$ such that $f(x) \to 0$ faster than $x \to \infty$.

Does this imply that $f'(x) \to 0$ faster than $x \to \infty$ too?

Comment: Do you mean that $f(x)\cdot x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$?

Comment: Well the general question is I have $xf'(x)$ and I know $f(x) \to 0$ faster than $x \to \infty$ so that $xf(x) = 0$ as $x \to \infty$. But I want to know does this mean I can also say that $xf'(x) = 0$ as $x \to \infty$?

Answer (score 9):

No. It's not even certain that $f'(x) \to 0$. Take, for instance,
$$
f(x) = e^{-x}\sin(e^x)
$$
which decreases exponentially to $0$, but the derivative alternates faster and faster between (a little less than) $-1$ and (a little more than) $1$ as $x$ grows.

Use $e^{-x}\sin(e^{2x})$ instead, and the derivative will even grow exponentially with $x$ (but alternate between positive and negative)

Comment: Say $f(x)$ was a probability distribution, i.e. $f(x) = P(x)$. Could I make the statement in that case?

Comment: @sonicboom No. Look at $k\cdot e^{-x}\sin^2(e^{-2x})$, which is always positive, and you can choose $k$ so that the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ is equal to $1$ (the function is between $e^{-x}$ and the $x$-axis, and therefore has finite integral). You still have the same property.

Comment: I mean, of course, $k\cdot e^{-x}\sin^2(e^{2x})$ in my comment above. Damn signs.

Comment: Don't we need the integral from $-\infty < x < \infty$ in the case of a probability distribution? And in this case the integral is unbounded on the negative $x$-axis...

Comment: @sonicboom If you let it go to $0$ from $x = 0$ to $x = -\epsilon$ for some small, positive $\epsilon$, and then keep it there for $x < -\epsilon$, the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ will be very close to the integral from $0$ to $\infty$. That can be mended by adjusting $k$ slightly. Of course, the functional experssion won't look as nice any more, but that does not stop such a function from existing, and it can be done so that the function is still infinitely continuously differentiable.